# Command line console for Unity 3d C#

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a command line console that I can try and execute lines of code in Unity?
Something like the Chrome console for javascript, or running python on the command line?
I am on windows 8.

I saw the immediate window in MonoDevelop, but it didn't seem to work without a debug session, and when I was debugging it said it wouldn't run when the application was running:

```
> this
The expression can't be evaluated while the application is running.
> this
Debug session not started.
```

It probably wanted to be at a breakpoint, which was not obvious to get working and kept crashing when I tried various ideas. I would rather just use the console independently from debugging - just to experiment with syntax etc.

What is the easiest way to bring up a console for executing lines of C# unity code?

Comment: The immediate window works only when you pause the attached process. You can use it to verify variables, change values and execute commands BUT ONLY if you pause the process (with the "pause" icon in the toolbar). It is not intended to be a unity console, is the debugger console :)

Comment: I keep encountering crashes when I try this. Perhaps because I attach it to my Unity 3d process. Is there a way to start a small independent script running and then pause that? Or another method altogether? I was slightly surprised that there was no input in the console in unity itself!

Comment: I gueess the best way to experiment is not to play with the console but to play with the code. We all do like this. We use the console just for debugging ;)